# qmake syntax: += vs. *= (plus vs. asterisk)

Tags: qt, qmake

What is the difference between the following statements, using a plus vs. an asterisk in .pro files?:

```
LIBS *= -lz
```

vs.

```
LIBS += -lz
```

Comment: Thanks for the negatives. If I had succeeded in finding that through SO or Google, I wouldn't have asked. Hence the keywords "equals" and "asterisk" to help future searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `*=` operator adds a value to the list of values in a variable, but only if it is not already present. This prevents values from being included many times in a variable.